# How to modify the page table of a Linux process?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I have one elf `p` linked to some dynamic libraries. I would like to modify the page table of `p` changing the address of some functions of the dynamic libraries in order to execute other functions whenever the modified ones are called. How can I achieve this goal? Is it different from patching the `GOT`?